# Bash Function for scraping gtfobins

Tags: bash, curl, sed, grep

I have created a bash function that checks gtfobins for a binary, if it exists it then displays the functions available for that binary. It then allows me to select a function name and it "should" return the exploit code for that specific binary function

example:
7z has two functions: File read and Sudo

**File read**
It reads data from files, it may be used to do privileged reads or disclose files outside a restricted file system.

```
LFILE=file_to_read
7z a -ttar -an -so $LFILE | 7z e -ttar -si -so
```

**Sudo**
If the binary is allowed to run as superuser by sudo, it does not drop the elevated privileges and may be used to access the file system, escalate or maintain privileged access.

```
LFILE=file_to_read
sudo 7z a -ttar -an -so $LFILE | 7z e -ttar -si -so
```

My code pulls the functions correctly but when I select the function it returns nothing.
I feel my issue is in the way the exploit information is being extracted but I just cant figure it out. I have used chatgpt to help analyze the code and it has gone through many different forms. The closest I have gotten is the code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
gtfo() {
    local binary="$1"
    local exploit_code

    # Query gtfobins.github.io for the exploit code
    exploit_code=$(curl -s "https://gtfobins.github.io/gtfobins/$binary/")

    # Check if exploit code exists
    if [[ $exploit_code == *"class=\"function-name\""* ]]; then
        # Extract the functions and exploit code from the HTML response
        local functions
        functions=$(echo "$exploit_code" | grep -oP '(?<=<h2 id=").*?(?=" class="function-name">)')
        local exploit_codes
        exploit_codes=$(echo "$exploit_code" | grep -oP '<pre><code>.*</code></pre>' | sed 's/<pre><code>//;s/<\/code><\/pre>//')

        # Create an array of functions
        IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a functions_array <<<"$functions"

        # Display the available functions
        echo "Available functions for $binary:"
        for ((i = 0; i < ${#functions_array[@]}; i++)); do
            echo "$(($i + 1)). ${functions_array[$i]}"
        done

        # Prompt for function selection
        read -p "Enter the function number to view the associated exploit: " selected_function_number

        # Validate the selected function number
        if [[ $selected_function_number =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && ((selected_function_number >= 1 && selected_function_number <= ${#functions_array[@]})); then
            local selected_function="${functions_array[$(($selected_function_number - 1))]}"
            local selected_exploit_code="${exploit_codes[$(($selected_function_number - 1))]}"

            # Print the exploit codes
            echo "Exploit codes for $selected_function:"
            echo "$selected_exploit_code"
        else
            echo "Invalid function number"
        fi
    else
        echo "No exploit found for $binary"
    fi
}
```

```
$ gtfo "7z"
Available functions for 7z:
1. file-read
2. sudo
Enter the function number to view the associated exploit: 1
Exploit codes for file-read:

$
```

## ***UPDATE***

After receiving user1934428's comment, I realized that there was an error in the code. The mentioned line was indeed being used incorrectly. Consequently, I dedicated some time to rewriting the entire code and managed to make it work correctly, or at least to the best of my ability. However, I still encountered difficulties in extracting the data directly from the "pre/code" tags for a specific "selected function name". As a workaround, I decided to retrieve the data from the  section with the function_names ID. After several hours of work and numerous edits, I finally achieved a somewhat functional version that I was satisfied with. To accomplish this, I utilized pup to extract the function names for the function array and employed awk to retrieve all the data from the "h2 id= " to "/pre". I also utilized multiple gsub operations to format the code properly, by replacing HTML entity codes with their respective text versions, and to clean up any unnecessary spaces. Also added some color. Without further delay, here is the rewritten code.

```
 gtfo() {
    # Check if a binary name is provided and if it contains only alphanumeric characters, underscores, and hyphens
    if [ -z "$1" ] || [[ ! "$1" =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$ ]]; then
        echo -e "Please provide a valid binary name with only \e[4;91malphanumeric characters\e[0m, \e[4;91munderscores\e[0m, and \e[4;91mhyphens\e[0m."
        return 1
    fi

    local binary="$1"
    local url="https://gtfobins.github.io/gtfobins/$binary/"

    # Query gtfobins.github.io for the binary
    local response=$(curl -s "$url")

    # Extract the list of functions and display
    local functions=$(echo "$response" | pup 'h2.function-name text{}' | sed 's/^\s*//;s/\s*$//' | sed '/^$/d')  # Remove leading/trailing spaces and empty lines

    # Check if there are any functions available
    if [ -z "$functions" ]; then
        echo -e "'\e[4;91m$binary\e[0m' not found in gtfobins database."
        return 1
    fi

    local i=1
    while IFS= read -r func; do
        echo "$i. $func"
        ((i++))
    done <<< "$functions"

    # Prompt for function selection
    read -p "Choose a function (enter the number): " choice

    # Validate the choice
    if ! [[ "$choice" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || [ "$choice" -lt 1 ] || [ "$choice" -gt "$i" ]; then
        echo -e "\e[4;91mInvalid choice\e[0m. Please enter a valid number."
        return 1
    fi

    # Retrieve the exploit code for the chosen function
    local chosen_func=$(echo "$functions" | sed -n "${choice}p" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed 's/ /-/g')
    local exploit=$(echo "$response" | awk -v chosen_func="$chosen_func" '/<h2 id="'$chosen_func'"/,/<\/pre>/ {gsub(/<\/?[^>]+>/, ""); gsub(/&lt;/, "<"); gsub(/&gt;/, ">"); gsub(/&amp;/, "\\x26"); gsub(/&quot;/, "\""); gsub(/&#39;/, "\x27"); sub(/^[[:space:]]+/, ""); if ($0 ~ /\S/) print $0;}')

    # Check if exploit code is empty
    if [ -z "$exploit" ]; then
        echo -e "No exploit code found."
        return 1
    fi

    # Display the chosen function and its exploit code
    echo -e "\n$exploit\n"
}
```

## output

```
gtfo 7z
1. File read
2. Sudo
Choose a function (enter the number): 1

File read
It reads data from files, it may be used to do privileged reads or disclose files outside a restricted file system.
LFILE=file_to_read
7z a -ttar -an -so $LFILE | 7z e -ttar -si -so
```

This was a headache because it took me a while to figure out how to get the code for the chosen function. If anyone sees a better/easier way to complete this I would be glad to see it

Comment: _it returns nothing_  : I don't understand the meaining of _returns_ here. We can see from your transscript,  that `selected_exploit_code` is empty, but it gets its value from the variable `exploit_codes`. You access this variable as if it were an array, but the variable is defined as a string. Perhaps this would be a starting point to research what is going on in your code.

Comment: Maybe returns was the wrong wording. What I mean is that when I select the function "1" like in the example it should scrape everything between the <pre><code></code></pre> tags from the website but this is not happening or at least it does not output that. Here is the HTML structure of the website ```<h2 id="file-read" class="function-name">File read</h2>
<p>It reads data from files, it may be used to do privileged reads or disclose files outside a restricted file system.</p>
<ul class="examples">
    <li>        
<pre><code>what I want extracted here</code></pre>
    </li>
</ul>```

Comment: Don't post so much code in a comment. Put it into your question. BTW, this still does not explain why you are using the variable `exploit_codes` as if it were an array.

Comment: Execute it without interactive and show us the exact command and the expected result.

Comment: I have updated the original post thanks for the comments :-) I would give "respect points" or whatever to both users but I don't know how sorry